# How to find the id looping through the array of objects using typescript and react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

i have data like below,

```
const items = [
    {
        id: '1',
        color: 'green',
        name: 'item1',
        polygons: [
            {
                id: '1', 
                coordinates: [
                    {
                        latitude: '25.00',
                        longitude: '-25.99',
                    }
                    {
                        latitude: '15.00',
                        longitude: '-25.99',
                    }
                    {
                        latitude: '25.00',
                        longitude: '-35.99',
                    }
                ],
            }
        ]
        subItems: [
            {
                id: '1', 
                name: 'subitem-1',
                color: 'green',
                polygons: [
                   {
                       id: '2', 
                       coordinates: [
                           {
                               latitude: '25.00',
                               longitude: '-25.99',
                           } 
                           {
                               latitude: '15.00',
                               longitude: '-25.99',
                           }
                           {
                               latitude: '25.00',
                               longitude: '-35.99',
                           }
                       ],
                   }
               ]
           }
       ],
   },
   {
       id: '2',
       color: 'red',
       name: 'item2',
       polygons: [
           {
               id: '3', 
               coordinates: [
                   {
                       latitude: '25.00',
                       longitude: '-25.99',
                   }
                   {
                       latitude: '15.00',
                       longitude: '-25.99',
                   }
                   {
                       latitude: '25.00',
                       longitude: '-35.99',
                   }
                ],
            }
        ]
        subItems: [
            {
                id: '2', 
                name: 'subitem-1',
                color: 'red',
                polygons: [
                    {
                        id: '5', 
                        coordinates: [
                           {
                               latitude: '25.00',
                               longitude: '-25.99',
                           }
                           {
                               latitude: '15.00',
                               longitude: '-25.99',
                           }
                           {
                               latitude: '25.00',
                               longitude: '-35.99',
                           }
                       ],
                   }
               ]
           }
       ],
   }
]
```

Now from above Items array i want to find index of subItems with id '2'.

i tried something like below,

```
const siIndex = Items.forEach(
    (item: any) =>
        item.subItems ?
            item.subItems.findIndex((subItem:any) => subItem.id === '2');//error here
    );
```

but this gives me parsing error ':' expected

how can i find the index of the subItem with id = '2' from the Items array. could someone help me with this.

I am not sure how to loop throught the Items array and find the index of subItem with id '2'.
thanks.

Comment: You are not correctly using the ternary operator. Please consult [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator#:~:text=The%20conditional%20%28ternary%29%20operator%20is%20the%20only%20JavaScript,expression%20to%20execute%20if%20the%20condition%20is%20falsy.). That is why you have the parsing error.

Comment: You need the `find` method. Take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/array/filter)

Comment: thanks. but you provide the snippet for my code as your answer.

Comment: @saritha there are multiple examples of using [array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/array/filter) as artur above showed. Please review that and attempt to fix the issue.

Comment: I was in not providing the answer to your question. SImply pointing you to the ressources necessary for you to fix the parseing error, and then filter, by yourself. If I wanted to answer, I would've posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct search can be done like this:

```js
items.findIndex((item) => item.subItems.some((sub) => sub.id == '2'))
```

Example:

```js
const items = [{
    id: '1',
    color: 'green',
    name: 'item1',
    polygons: [{
      id: '1',
      coordinates: [{
          latitude: '25.00',
          longitude: '-25.99',
        },
        {
          latitude: '15.00',
          longitude: '-25.99',
        },
        {
          latitude: '25.00',
          longitude: '-35.99',
        }
      ],
    }],
    subItems: [{
      id: '1',
      name: 'subitem-1',
      color: 'green',
      polygons: [{
        id: '2',
        coordinates: [{
            latitude: '25.00',
            longitude: '-25.99',
          },
          {
            latitude: '15.00',
            longitude: '-25.99',
          },
          {
            latitude: '25.00',
            longitude: '-35.99',
          }
        ],
      }]
    }],
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    color: 'red',
    name: 'item2',
    polygons: [{
      id: '3',
      coordinates: [{
          latitude: '25.00',
          longitude: '-25.99',
        },
        {
          latitude: '15.00',
          longitude: '-25.99',
        },
        {
          latitude: '25.00',
          longitude: '-35.99',
        }
      ],
    }],
    subItems: [{
      id: '2',
      name: 'subitem-1',
      color: 'red',
      polygons: [{
        id: '5',
        coordinates: [{
            latitude: '25.00',
            longitude: '-25.99',
          },
          {
            latitude: '15.00',
            longitude: '-25.99',
          },
          {
            latitude: '25.00',
            longitude: '-35.99',
          }
        ],
      }]
    }],
  }
]

const itemIndex = items.findIndex((item) => item.subItems.some((sub) => sub.id == '2'));

console.log('Item index with subItems with id=2 is:', itemIndex)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a.findIndex(b => b.subItem.id ===2)
```

try the above solution. here a is the list you're using

but I have a solution/example

you have some structure like
const a = [{id:'some1', subItem:{ id:1}},{id:'some2', subItem:{ id:2}}]

Below will return index for subItem with ID === 2

a.findIndex(b => b.subItem.id === 2);

```js
const a = [{id:'some1', subItem:{ id:1}},{id:'some2', subItem:{ id:2}}]

//Below will return index for subItem with ID === 2
a.findIndex(b => b.subItem.id === 2);

to get both indexes

const matchedItemIndex    = a.findIndex(b => b.subItem.id === 2);// return matched itemIndex
const matchedItem    = a.find(b => b.subItem.id === 2);
const matchedSubItemIndex   = a[matchedItemIndex].findIndex(b => b.id === matchedItem.id);// return mamtching subItemIndex
```

Comment: you want matching index from subItem array or the items array?

Comment: i want to check in both the subItem and items array too.

Comment: then u need write a function and to keep all matching indexes

Answer (score 0):

You can run nested loops, or you can access the subitems directly and use some or filter  but if you wanted full recursion here's a fairly verbose gist for the sake of explaining

```
const iterate = (obj) => {
  // loop through object properties
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      // do something with the current iteration
      
      if (typeof value === 'object') {
        // if the property value is an object then iterate into that object
        iterate(value)
      }
    }
  });
};

iterate(items);
```