# How to recursively loop through array of objects and find the index of matching id using javascript and react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Hi i have data like below,

```
const items = [
    {
        id: '1',
        color: 'green',
        name: 'item1',
        polygons: [
            {
                id: '1', 
                coordinates: [
                    {
                        latitude: '25.00',
                        longitude: '-25.99',
                    }
                    {
                        latitude: '15.00',
                        longitude: '-25.99',
                    }
                    {
                        latitude: '25.00',
                        longitude: '-35.99',
                    }
                ],
            }
        ]
        subItems: [
            {
                id: '2', 
                name: 'subitem-1',
                color: 'green',
                polygons: [
                   {
                       id: '2', 
                       coordinates: [
                           {
                               latitude: '25.00',
                               longitude: '-25.99',
                           } 
                           {
                               latitude: '15.00',
                               longitude: '-25.99',
                           }
                           {
                               latitude: '25.00',
                               longitude: '-35.99',
                           }
                       ],
                   }
               ]
           }
       ],
   },
]
```

**what i am trying to do?**

from the Items array i want to find the index that matches with id = '2' using javascript or typescript.

so basically item and subItem have different ids and they never match and i want to loop through each item and check if its id matches with id 2 and check each subitem of that item and check if id matches to 2.

if matches return the index.

i have tried something like below,

```
const ItemIndex = Items.findIndex(
    (Item: any) => Item.id === '2'
);
```

this will check only for the Item but not within subItems. how can i modify this code to check for the subItems id too?

could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: So do subItems has more subItems too?

Comment: yes subItems is an array of objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a duplicate [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63475920/how-to-find-the-id-looping-through-the-array-of-objects-using-typescript-and-rea/), but OK, I can answer here too.

The correct search can be done like this:

```js
items.findIndex((item) => item.subItems.some((sub) => sub.id == '2'))
```

Example:

```js
const items = [{
    id: '1',
    color: 'green',
    name: 'item1',
    polygons: [{
      id: '1',
      coordinates: [{
          latitude: '25.00',
          longitude: '-25.99',
        },
        {
          latitude: '15.00',
          longitude: '-25.99',
        },
        {
          latitude: '25.00',
          longitude: '-35.99',
        }
      ],
    }],
    subItems: [{
      id: '1',
      name: 'subitem-1',
      color: 'green',
      polygons: [{
        id: '2',
        coordinates: [{
            latitude: '25.00',
            longitude: '-25.99',
          },
          {
            latitude: '15.00',
            longitude: '-25.99',
          },
          {
            latitude: '25.00',
            longitude: '-35.99',
          }
        ],
      }]
    }],
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    color: 'red',
    name: 'item2',
    polygons: [{
      id: '3',
      coordinates: [{
          latitude: '25.00',
          longitude: '-25.99',
        },
        {
          latitude: '15.00',
          longitude: '-25.99',
        },
        {
          latitude: '25.00',
          longitude: '-35.99',
        }
      ],
    }],
    subItems: [{
      id: '2',
      name: 'subitem-1',
      color: 'red',
      polygons: [{
        id: '5',
        coordinates: [{
            latitude: '25.00',
            longitude: '-25.99',
          },
          {
            latitude: '15.00',
            longitude: '-25.99',
          },
          {
            latitude: '25.00',
            longitude: '-35.99',
          }
        ],
      }]
    }],
  }
]

const itemIndex = items.findIndex((item) => item.subItems.some((sub) => sub.id == '2'));

console.log('Item index with subItems with id=2 is:', itemIndex)
```

Comment: thanks. but doesnt this search for id only within subItems?

Comment: @someuser2491 so you need to find index of item if a) item has id=2, b) if item's subItems have id=2? So any of this or both?

Comment: @someuser2491 if it is not recursive, then the answer will be: `const itemIndex = items.findIndex((item) => item.id == '2' || item.subItems.some((sub) => sub.id == '2'));`

Comment: @someuser2491 you can convert this to a function: `const getIndex = (v) => items.findIndex((item) => item.id == v || item.subItems.some((sub) => sub.id == v));` and use it with any ID you want: `console.log('Item index with subItems with id=1 is:', getIndex(1))`